# Python subprocess exception handling

Tags: python, c++, exception, visual-studio-2012, subprocess

I have a program written in C++ and all it does is divide 1/0 to produce an exception.

I run the .exe of this program via Python's subprocess library. My goal is to capture and log the exception that C++ program makes, within Python.

```
p = subprocess.Popen(['C:\\Users\\name\\Desktop\\Win32Project1.exe'])
```

When this line of code executes p is a non zero value meaning an error has occured.
I'm running windows 7 and using Python 3.4.1

Comment: Depending on how much control you need you will need to handle stdout and stderr pipes + wait() for the return value.  Maybe [check_output](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output) does the job for you?

Comment: _When this line of code executes p is a non zero value meaning an error has occured_ - no, that's not what happens. `subprocess.Popen` returns a Popen object that is never zero. You can call `p.wait()` and get the return code if you'd like.

Answer (score 0):

I'm quite sure you can't track exceptions from a different process.
You should try-catch the exception within the C++ program and pass it by one of the many inter-process communication means.

HTH,
Cabbi

Comment: When I run the process with windbg, it tracks the exception and logs the error, so it must be possible, yeah? Going through the C++ code and modifying it would not be an option in my case.

Comment: You can use python to interact with a platform's debug facilities. I searched [call windows debug hooks from python](https://www.google.com/search?client=ubuntu&channel=fs&q=call+windows+debug+hooks+from+python&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8) and got some interesting answers like [winappdbg](http://winappdbg.sourceforge.net/). But to be fair to @cabbi, you kinda blindsided him here by not mentioning that you are trying to write a debugger. For most users, you don't try to grab an exception from other programs.

Comment: The best solution I've found and might work (I didn't test it) is starting the process in a new Application Domain. Here an example in C#: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/62259e21-3280-4d10-a27c-740d35efe51c/catch-another-process-unhandled-exception?forum=csharpgeneral

Comment: @tdelaney winappdbg is what ultimately solved my problem, Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
cmd = ['C:\\Users\\name\\Desktop\\Win32Project1.exe']
out, err = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()
print out  # this prints the output of the execution
print err  # this prints if any error is returned
```

I don't have windows, so this is not tested, but might help you, for more info have a look [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can also pass other parameters to subprocess.Popen that specify where stdin and stderr go.

Then you can say **something** like:

```
p = subprocess.Popen('C:\\Users\\name\\Desktop\\Win32Project1.exe', stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
(stdout_data, stderr_data) = p.communicate()

rc = p.returncode

# assume 0 return code means o.k.
if rc:
  parse_error(stderr_data)
  # end if
```